# XSLT Move child elements into new parent node

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am very new to XSLT and trying to transform this XML:

```
<Company>
   <Employee>
       <name>Jane</name>
       <id>200</id>
       <title>Dir</title>
       <name>Joe</name>
       <id>100</id>
       <title>Mgr</title>
       <name>Sue</name>
       <id>300</id>
       <title>Analyst</title>
   </Employee>
 </Company>
```

To this expected output:

```
<Company>
   <Employee>
       <name>Jane</name>
       <id>200</id>
       <title>Dir</title>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
       <name>Joe</name>
       <id>100</id>
       <title>Mgr</title>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
       <name>Sue</name>
       <id>300</id>
       <title>Analyst</title>
   </Employee>
</Company>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can one assume a  uniform structure of {name; id; title}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they always come in groups of three, you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Company">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Employee/name">
            <Employee>
                <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::id[1] | following-sibling::title[1]"/>
            </Employee>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or more generic:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="group-size" select="3" />

<xsl:template match="/Company">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Employee/*[position() mod $group-size = 1]">
            <Employee>
                <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::*[position() &lt; $group-size]"/>
            </Employee>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry I just now had a chance to respond.  In the original XML they always come in groups of three.  I tried your suggestion in the stylesheet and it worked.  Thank you!